# Multiple simple NotifierProviders better than one "bigger" NotifierProvider with a class as state?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have a class AppState with a few properties, p1, p2, ...,pn. I now implemented a NotifierProvider for that class.

Would it be better, to create a few extra NotifierProviders for each property, so that a change (e.g. only p1) in the big AppState-NotifierProvider would not cause updates of many widgets, that relay on state, that hasn´t changed in Appstate (e.g. Widget W1 only uses p2 from the AppState). Would W1 update in the case only p1 is updated in AppState?

Comment: yes, create a provider for each to avoid unnecessary rebuilds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only reason for creating multiple providers is reducing widget rebuilds, that's unnecessary.

Riverpod has a built-in way to optimize rebuilds in such cases: `select`

```dart
class ConsumerExample extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // Instead of writing:
    // String name = ref.watch(provider).firstName!;
    // We can write:
    String name = ref.watch(exampleProvider.select((it) => it.firstName));
    // This will cause the widget to only listen to changes on "firstName".

    return Text('Hello $name');
  }
}
```

https://riverpod.dev/docs/advanced/select